# Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug'

Tags: android, gradle, data-binding, build.gradle

I am getting the following error while trying to do Gradle build:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug'.
> not a valid name: continue
```

I have searched in files for the `continue` keyword if any class or something is named as `continue` but couldn't find one.

Here is my build.gradle(:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.faisan"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 13
        versionName "V0.1.3"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.2.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:20.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    // google map and location
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'

    // to get location co-ordinates (permission + location handler)
    implementation 'com.github.mumayank:AirLocation:1.3.1'

    //! please don't remove, upgrade (only add) any dependencies.
    // xrv
//    implementation 'com.jcodecraeer:xrecyclerview:1.6.0'

    // retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'

    // lottie animation
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.5.0'

    // Picasso for Image stuff
    // important: latest 2.71.. doesn't seems to work! so don't upgrade to latest
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    // for circling image with this via Picasso
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.2.1'

    // room, worker (Google JetPack) | Database and Background Worker
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.6.0"

    // ramotion card slider
    // see https://github.com/Ramotion/cardslider-android
    // implementation 'com.ramotion.cardslider:card-slider:0.3.1'

    // bus stop list (timeline view)
    // see https://github.com/vipulasri/Timeline-View
    implementation 'com.github.vipulasri:timelineview:1.1.5'


    // animated progressbar button
    implementation 'com.github.razir.progressbutton:progressbutton:2.1.0'

    // otp
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.5.1'

    // kotlin required for button progress anim library
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    // in app update (don't update the version as 1.10.0+ doesn't seem to work)
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.0'


}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

And here is my build.gradle (Faisan) [App's name is Faisan]

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

What is "continue" here? What am I missing here? Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Check your layout files & check the views if they have `continue` as their id.

Comment: there was an id with the name "continue_", not "continue". I have changed that name to something else and it started to work. Don't know why lol!. Thanks a bunch, mate.

Comment: continue is a language level keyword so that’s why it caused an error when generating binding classes, great to see that it is solved.